# Render is not able to changed the color of back ground

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private render : Renderer2) { }

  @ViewChild('box', { static: false }) box: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.render.setStyle(this.box.nativeElement,'backgroundColor','red');  }

}


<div #box>

    <p > from rendere</p>

</div>
```

core.js:6228 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

I am trying to change the colour of div by reader following is not able to change it. accessing the div by the template ref nad view child

Comment: `ngOnInit` hook might be too soon to access the DOM. Try to access it in `ngAfterViewInit` hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View queries are set before the `ngAfterViewInit` callback is called. Check please [link](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit{        
    constructor(private render : Renderer2) { }        
    @ViewChild('box', { static: false }) box: ElementRef;
    ngOnInit(): void {}
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.render.setStyle(this.box.nativeElement,'backgroundColor','red');       
    }  
}
```